# How to get the name of class as type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Such as here, how can I get the name of class as type in typescript

```js
class Foo {}
type Name = ClassName<Foo>; // "Foo"
```

Comment: I strongly suspect you can't. You can get a string for it easily enough (`Foo.name`, assuming `Foo`'s name hasn't been changed by minification), but not as a *type* I don't think. Still, TypeScript is very large, underdocumented, and powerful, and I'm still only at a journeyman stage with it, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @JeanRemyDuboc No, I wanna get the type `"Foo"`, not value

Comment: This isn't possible. What's the use case you have in mind?

Comment: @AluanHaddad in my envisaged case, user can use the generic to extend a mapping type easily, like `type mapping = Bar<Foo>; // { foo: Foo; }`. If it cannot be achieved, i would try the other way

Comment: @SilveryStar It may help if you describe your use case(s) in the question, so people can get a feeling for what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: @SilveryStar - I'm really not understanding your example in the comment above. Please do update the question to clarify how you would be using the type.